# Is there anyway we can read data from sms and show an entry in IOS using flutter?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, flutter-test, mobile-development

I am new to flutter. I am working on an app where to show every entry the server sends an sms and fetching data from that sms shows the entry for which it was sent. Its just like the OTP fetching but instead it is done everytime a new order comes and the server sends a message. My boss have the code for andriod but they want to implement it in IOS as well. Is there anyway to read sms and show the entry using flutter?

Comment: An app cannot read sms messages on iOS as it would be a privacy violation.   If you set the content type of a text field to "OTP" then iOS will provide the code from a text message in the quick type bar

Comment: Sorry for late reply. What my boss wants to do is to receive a message from server and after decrypting that message it shows an entry i.e the order that they received. After that when he approves the order a message should be sent to server and then the driver gets approval of that that to be shipped. They have implemented that in android but since I am intern so they won't be providing me the code and I'll have to do it on my own.

Comment: Apps on iOS can't read sms text messages.  Is using push notifications an option?

Comment: I talked to my boss. He said if its not possible then can we Copy paste that long string which app will decrypt and show the entry for that string. Also can we do like when he approves the order a message is automatically sent to the driver. Using push notification isn't an option according to him (my boss).

Comment: @Paulw11 can you get on this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I guess you could send a base64 encoded string as a text message that the user could then copy and paste into your app. Seems like a very unfriendly and cumbersome process